# Pycharm: ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: pycharm

Не хочет анаконда работать. Я установил ssl пакет и все равно результата ноль.

```
C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Modul5\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=50765
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 5, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.rpc import make_rpc_client, start_rpc_server, start_rpc_server_and_make_client
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\rpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_comm.server import TSingleThreadedServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.server import TServer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _shaded_thriftpy.transport import (
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .sslsocket import TSSLSocket, TSSLServerSocket  # noqa
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\transport\sslsocket.py", line 7, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создание conda окружения должны поправить в 2019.1.1 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33527 По второму сриншоту похоже что обычное виртуальное окружение было создано из PyCharm с базовым интерпретатором в виде конды. Так лучше не делать - либо создайте conda environment в терминале и добавьте в PyCharm, либо не используйте конду в принципе.